How to find out if columns are used in views/are queried in BigQuery?
I am trying to find out which columns are not being used and which are used in views and queries in BigQuery.
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS has only 2 records and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS does not contain column_name column.
I wanted to join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS on some of the query logging tables but I cant find out how to link it to columns usage.

For now it's not possible to get columns without properly parsing the query history.

Thank you everybody. What I did to solve my problem - I have created sql script with using regexp on query column in information_schema.jobs and extracted column names from this field directly. Not the most simple solution but that really helped.
Here is my script(of course it needs some adjustments if aliases are used in the queries etc...):
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    reftab.dataset_id AS dataset_id,
    reftab.table_id AS table_id,
 --   QUERY,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(query, r'`(\w+)`') AS column_names
  FROM
    `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS AS job,
    UNNEST(job.referenced_tables) AS reftab
  --WHERE DATE(job.creation_time) >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -150 DAY)
  AND reftab.dataset_id IN .....
)

SELECT
  dataset_id,
  table_id,
  column_name,
  COUNT(*) AS column_usage_count,
--  QUERY
FROM (
  SELECT
    dataset_id,
    table_id,
 --   QUERY,
    ARRAY(
      SELECT DISTINCT column_name
      FROM UNNEST(column_names) AS column_name
      WHERE NOT LOWER(column_name) IN (
        'select', 'from', 'where', 'join', 'on', 'group', 'by', 'order', 'limit', 'having', 'case', 'when',
        'else', 'end', 'as', 'over', 'partition', 'and', 'or', 'in', 'between', 'like', 'not', 'is', 'null',
        'left', 'right', 'inner', 'outer', 'full', 'cross', 'exists', 'union', 'distinct', 'count', 'avg', 'sum',
        'min', 'max', 'cast', 'convert', 'date_add', 'date_sub', 'date_diff', 'date_trunc', 'current_date',
        'current_timestamp', 'date', 'timestamp', 'time', 'datetime', 'array', 'struct', 'any', 'some', 'all',
        'extract', 'concat', 'bde', 'prod', 'gcp', 'counts'
      )
    ) AS column_names
  FROM
    cte
) t, UNNEST(column_names) AS column_name
WHERE
  column_name IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
  dataset_id,
  table_id,
  column_name--,
 -- QUERY
ORDER BY
  dataset_id,
  table_id,
  column_name;

